# Pandas - Create a symmetric matrix that counts the number of records

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the one below

```
ID  |  Value
1   |  A
1   |  B
1   |  C
2   |  B
2   |  C
```

I want to create a symmetric matrix of based on Value:

```
    A   B  C
 A  1   1  1
 B  1   2  2
 C  1   2  2
```

This basically indicates how many people have both values (v1,v2). I am currently using for loops to scan the dataframe for every combination but was wondering if there was an easier way to do it using pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use merge with cross join by `ID` column with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove index and columns names:

```
df = pd.merge(df, df, on='ID')

df = pd.crosstab(df['Value_x'], df['Value_y']).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C
A  1  1  1
B  1  2  2
C  1  2  2
```

Comment: 'Value_x' and 'Value_y' are to be specified or are they inbuilt keywords? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Nivi - It is `index` and `columns` names created from columns names after `crosstab`